# Validator requirements

Tags: validator

Solana aims to be the fastest blockchain in the world. OK, specifically the fastest public blockchain that run smart contracts. I believe they indeed have reached that goal.

Let's assume I were to fork the Solana source code in order to create a special purpose blockchain, which does NOT need to be the fastest in the world. And let's further assume I like PoH and so many things about Solana, so I want to fork my chain off of Solana rather than say Tendermint.

So now, in my Solanoid chain, I want to drastically reduce validator requirements with regards to CPU power (i.e. PoH hashrate) as well as network bandwidth requirements. I want to do that because I want to appeal to a broader audience to run validator nodes for my chain, and also because just don't need the world-class speed for my special purpose.

Would Solana just work out of the box if all validators just run on slower CPUs and 30Mbps network instead of 300Mbps?

My hope is the PoH "clock" rate will just be slower, fewer transactions can be processed per second because of the slower bandwidth, but otherwise the Solana source code will need minimal adaptations to work with slower validators.

Is my hope correct? Or are there any special dependencies in the source that it MUST have validator requirements that Solana currently has?